# How can you compress the view of a graph in R Studio? (having trouble seeing data after shrinking x and y axis and changing fill color)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Running this code was successful:

```
POP_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = average_POP, )) +
  geom_col(color = "blue", width = .7, alpha =1) +
  labs(title = "Average Total Population From 2000 to 2015",
       x = "Year",
       y= "Average Total Population (in thousands)")
```

Just as some background, I ran the following code to get the POP_data dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

new_dates <- economics %>% 
  filter(date >= as.Date("2000-01-01") & date <= as.Date("2015-12-31")) %>% 
  select(date, pce, pop, unemploy)

grouped_data <- group_by(new_dates, year = lubridate::year(date))

aggregated_data <- summarise(grouped_data, average_PCE = mean(pce), 
                             average_POP = mean(pop), 
                             average_UNEMPLOY = mean(unemploy))

POP_data <- aggregated_data %>% 
  select(year, average_POP) %>% 
  view
```

To try and shrink my y axis because the range was relatively small in comparison to the entire axis, I ran the following code (I also attempted to change the fill of the bars which I was successful in doing through the "MyColor" function and "scale_fill_manual"):

```
POP_data %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = average_POP, fill = "MyColor")) +
  geom_col(color = "blue", width = .7, alpha = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = "blue") +
  labs(title = "Average Total Population From 2000 to 2015",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Average Total Populaiton (in thousands)") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2000, 2015), 
                     breaks = seq(2000, 2015, by = 5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(270000000, 330000000), 
                     breaks = seq(270000000, 330000000, by = 20000000))
```

I attempted to incorporate the na.omit function after the first pipe, but that didn't work. I would truly appreciate any help and explanation anyone would be willing to offer!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: maybe log transform ationis an option?

Comment: `scale_y_continuous(limits = ` will filter out any data that is outside that range, including your bars since they start at y = 0. (I know, most people don't expect this.) You want `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2.7E5, 3.3E5))` instead of setting y limits in `scale_y_continuous`.

Comment: From the help for `?scale_y_continuous`: "Note that setting limits on positional scales will remove data outside of the limits. If the purpose is to zoom, use the limit argument in the coordinate system (see coord_cartesian())."

Comment: @JonSpring that worked to perfection; thank you so much! To your point, I definitely did not expect it (scale_y_continuous restricting data, but it makes total sense). If I may ask, how were you able to find that out or how did you know that? years of experience? another forum? thank you again for your help!

Comment: Here's a good resource: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/graphics-for-communication.html#zooming

Comment: @user12256545 I ended up incorporating the coord_cartesian function and it worked! Thanks so much for your time and willingness to help